# CSS Circle image with CSS overlay overflow

Tags: html, css

I have a an image, 500 px height and width. I used border-radius to make it a circle image. I also have a solid background color that I use border-radius on to make it a circle as well.

I am trying to create an overlay on hover by reducing the opacity of the image, letting the background image peer through. I have it basically working, although there is about a 1px overlap of showing the background image on the bottom of the actual image.

[image]

**Snippet:**

```css
 .image-wrapper {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background-color: #000;
     border-radius: 50%;
     margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    img {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img class="testing red" src="img.jpg">
 </div>
```

As you can see from the example there is about one pixel of the background showing at the bottom of the image before any hover.

Comment: i was dimmed image when hover with opacity...Try my answer, may me this will help u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue here is that **img** has *display: inline* by default.
You can fix it by setting your **img** to *display: block* in your CSS

```css
.image-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img class="testing red" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this css:

```
.image-wrapper{
    width:128px;
    margin: 10px;
    border:10px solid red;
    border-radius: 500px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 500px;
    -moz-border-radius: 500px;
}
```

Here is the sample example for you question,hope this will help you.
http://jsfiddle.net/z3rLa/1/

Answer (score 0):

```css
.image-overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border:2px solid #000;
}
.image-overlay:hover {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    opacity:0.5;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-overlay">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSODZIzJ1LLVMxlyd4RKB8TmvAeufTRGolSlX64IagMNtWvo4ij">
</div>
```